# Rudin's proof of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis

Here is what he wrote in his Principles of Mathematical Analysis

> **7.25     Theorem**      If $K$ is compact, if $f_n \in \mathscr{C}(K)$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots,$ and if $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise bounded and equicontinuous on $K$, then
>
> 1. $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $K$,
> 2. $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence.
>
> **Proof**
>
> (1) Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and choose $\delta > 0$, in accordance with Definition 7.22, so that
> \begin{equation}
> |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \varepsilon \tag{44}
> \end{equation}
> for all $n$, provided that $d(x,y) < \delta$.
>
> Since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $p_1, \dots, p_r$ in $K$ such that to every $x \in K$ corresponds at least one $p_i$ with $d(x, p_i) < \delta$. Since $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise bounded, there exist $M_i < \infty$ such that $|f_n(p_i)| < M_i$ for all $n$. If $M = \max(M_1, \dots, M_r)$, then $|f_n(x)| < M + \varepsilon$ for every $x \in K$. This proves (1).
>
> (2) Let $E$ be a countable dense subset of $K$. (For the existence of such a set $E$, see Exercise 25, Chap. 2.) Theorem 7.23 shows that $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_i}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_i}(x)\}$ converges for every $x \in E$.
>
> Put $f_{n_i} = g_i$, to simplify the notation. We shall prove that $\{g_i\}$ converrges uniformly on $K$.
>
> Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and pick $\delta > 0$ as in the beginning of this proof. Let $V(x,\delta)$ be the set of all $y \in K$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$. Since $E$ is dense in $K$, and $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $x_1, \dots, x_m$ in $E$ such that
> $$
> K \subset V(x_1, \delta) \cup \dots \cup V(x_m, \delta). \tag{45}
> \label{45}
> $$
>
> Since $\{g_i(x)\}$ converges for every $x \in E$, there is an integer $N$ such that
> $$
> |g_i(x_s) - g_j(x_s)| < \varepsilon \tag{46}
> \label{46}
> $$
> whenever $i \geq N$, $j \geq N$, $1 \leq s \leq m$.
>
> If $x \in K$, $(\ref{45})$ shows that $x \in V(x_s, \delta)$ for some $s$, so that
> $$
> |g_i(x) - g_i(x_s) | < \varepsilon
> $$
> for every $i$. If $i \geq N$ and $j \geq N$, it follows from $(\ref{46})$ that
> \begin{align}
> |g_i(x) - g_j(x)| &\leq |g_i(x) - g_i(x_s)| + |g_i(x_s) - g_j(x_s)| + |g_j(x_s) - g_j(x)| \\
> &< 3\varepsilon.
> \end{align}
> This completes the proof.

In his Real and Complex Analysis, he wrote

> 11.28 Theorem (Arzela-Ascoli) Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is pointwise bounded equicontinous collection of complex functions on a metric space $X$, and that $X$ contains a countable dense subset $E$. Every subsequence $\{f_n\}$ is $\mathscr{F}$ has then a subsequence that converges uniformly on every compact subset of $X$.

It the fact (and assumption) that a countable dense subset of compact metric spaces exists really necessary?

Since $\cup_{x\in K}V(x,\delta)\supset K$, (45) holds for finitely many points $x_1,...,x_m$ in $K$. Theorem 7.23 (diagonal process) shows that $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{g_n\}$ such that $\{g_n(x_j)\}$ converges for $j=1,2,...,m$, and the argument after display (45) folows.

Edit: my argument does not work because the subsequence $\{g_n\}$ is not given before the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: I don't know what he wrote specifically but the argument I know relies crucially on separability since it basically finds a subsequence converging on the countable dense subset using a diagonal argument and then argues by equicontinuity that it then converges elsewhere also.

Comment: That said a compact metric space is automatically separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why separability?**

> It the fact (and assumption) that a countable dense subset of compact metric spaces exists really necessary?

When I first saw this proof, I had this exact question! If $K$ is not separable (i.e., it does not have a countable, dense subset), then (45) doesn't hold for some $\delta > 0$. To see this, we can argue the contrapositive. Assume (45) holds for all $\delta > 0$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find a finite set of points $X_n$ such that
$$
K \subset \bigcup_{x \in X_n} B_{1 / n}(x),
\quad \text{where $B_{1 / n}(x) = \{y \in X : d(x, y) < 1 / n\}$}.
$$
Take $E = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty X_n$. I'll leave it to you to check that $E$ is a countable dense subset of $K$.

---

**Why separability of the metric space $X$?**

In *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Rudin assumes $K$ is compact, hence implying $K$ is separable. On the other hand, in *Real and Complex Analysis*, Rudin does not assume $X$ is compact, but instead identifies a subsequence that converges uniformly in *every* compact subset of $X$. Notice the difference here. To find a subsequence that converges uniformly in every compact subset of $X$ requires considering $X$ in its entirety, not just an arbitrary compact subset (imagine $X = \mathbb{R}$, where there is no “largest” compact subset). Of course, $X$ is not necessarily compact, so we do need to require that it is at least separable.

---

**Why your argument won't work**

(Taking this from my comment below because it's important) You need the last line of Rudin's proof to hold for *all* $\varepsilon > 0$. Note that the choice of $x_1, \dots, x_m$ depends on the choice of $\delta$, which depends on the choice of $\varepsilon$. So if you only find a subsequence that converges pointwise to finitely many points, the last line may be satisfied for some $\varepsilon$, but not all. This should make intuitive sense because a subsequence that converges on finitely many points clearly need not converge everywhere.

Comment: $\cup_{x\in K} V(x,\delta)$ is an open cover of $K$, hence, there are finitely many points $x_1, x_2,...,x_m$ such that (45) holds.

Comment: Well, what you just said proves that a compact set is separable.

Comment: I edited my answer, so hopefully the contrapositive is clear now.

Comment: Isn't compactness of $K$ enough?

Comment: Sure, but compactness implies separability. I guess the statement of the theorem in *Real and Complex Analysis* is more general because it only requires separability, and not compactness.

Comment: It does require compactness.

Comment: > on every compact subset of $X$

Comment: Welp, I can't read, you're right.

Comment: Well actually, no. See the update to my answer.

Comment: A quick question: for the theorem in PoMA does my argument work? And he provides a proof that works in a more general context?

Comment: No, I just realized it won't work. You need the last line of the proof to hold for ALL $\varepsilon$. Note that the choice of $x_1, \dots, x_m$ depends on $\delta$, which depends on $\varepsilon$. So if you only find a subsequence that converges pointwise to finitely many points, the last line may be satisfied for some $\varepsilon$, but not all.